# How to add a '---' in front of each line of a file, only if it doesn't exist using awk/sed in Linux?

Tags: awk, sed

I have a file that should have three dashed lines --- at the start of each line (or in column 1). However, in some lines, there is no dashed lines --- and instead starts with my gene variant (which should belong in column 2). **I need a way to insert these dashed lines --- in the front of every line IF it is not present in column 1.**

Another additional problem is that, where there is no --- dashed lines in column 1, the column 2 value is present in both column 1 and 2. I need to delete the repeated value. So these gene value is only present in column 2.

For example, inside the file looks like:

```
rs5838651 rs5838651
chr2_218715351_C_T chr2_218715351_C_T
--- rs12476661
```

I need it to look like

```
--- rs5838651
--- chr2_218715351_C_T
--- rs12476661:
```

Thank you in advance for any help/advice!

Comment: You may be overcomplicating this. What's wrong with just setting the first column to `---` regardless? Like `awk '{$1="---"}1' file`

Comment: What did you try up to now? Can you show us? There is a trailing colon (`:`) at the end of the last line of your expected output. Is it a typo or is it on purpose?

Answer (score 2):

```
$ awk '{$1="---"}1' File
```

Disregarding anything, replace the first column by the three hyphens and print the line (default action on pattern `1`)

Answer (score 1):

This might work for you (GNU sed):

```
sed -E '/^---\s/!s/^(\S+)\s\1/--- \1/' file
```

If a line does not begin with `---` , remove the second column and insert `---` .

Answer (score 0):

How about this:

```
sed "s/^[^-]/--- /g" < yourfile
```

Comment: Always use singe quotes unless you need double and the `g` at the end  is doing nothing but possibly slowing down your script since the regexp can only match once. `sed 's/^[^-]/--- /g' < yourfile`

Comment: Would not `[^-]` match just first characters rather than first column content?

Comment: That's right, yes. The ^[^-] matches any line where the first *character* is not a hyphen. The original data looked to be machine-generated, but agreed that assumption may not always be true

Answer (score 0):

Using GNU `sed`, let `file.txt` be

```
rs5838651 rs5838651
chr2_218715351_C_T chr2_218715351_C_T
--- rs12476661
```

then

```
sed 's/^[^[:space:]]*/---/' file.txt
```

output

```
--- rs5838651
--- chr2_218715351_C_T
--- rs12476661
```

Explanation: replace all leading non-whitespaces using `---`.

(tested in [GNU sed live editor](https://sed.js.org/))